# Operator Overloading behaves differently for classes and primtives

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

The following code when compiled and run using g++ outputs `22`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a = 5;
    int c = ++a + ++a + ++a;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Floats also evaluate to the same value.

Whereas the following integer wrapper class outputs `24`

```
#include <iostream>

class Int{
public:
    int data;
    
    Int( int value ) : data(value){}
    
    Int& operator++(){
       ++data;
       return *this;
    }
    
    Int operator+( const Int& b ){
        return Int( data + b.data );
    }
    
};

int main(){
    Int a = 5;
    Int c = ++a + ++a + ++a;
    std::cout << c.data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to understand why is there a difference in the outputs.

- The first thing that came to my mind was the order of evaluation but shouldn't it be same for ints as well a classes.
- I also thought if my implementation was wrong but most text also mentions the same implementation for prefix increment operator.

Could someone explain me in detail whats going on here?

Apart from this when both codes are compiled using `clang` the first code outputs `21` while the second code outputs `22`.

**PS : I know i shouldn't be using such an expression but my question is why are classes behaving differently than primitive types. Shouldn't they both parse to the same syntax tree and get evaluated in the same order. Even though the behaviour is undefined but for the same compiler, shouldn't they both behave in a similar manner**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `int c = ++a + ++a + ++a;` and `Int c = ++a + ++a + ++a;` result in undefined behavior.
You should avoid coding like that.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec#Example,

and see the [*Undefined behaviour* section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior) of cppreference.com's *Order of evaluation* page:

> ### Undefined behavior
>
> 1. If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to another side effect on the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.
>
>    ```
>    i = ++i + 2;       // undefined behavior until C++11
>    i = i++ + 2;       // undefined behavior until C++17
>    f(i = -2, i = -2); // undefined behavior until C++17
>    f(++i, ++i);       // undefined behavior until C++17, unspecified after C++17
>    i = ++i + i++;     // undefined behavior
>    ```
> 2. If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.
>
>    ```
>    cout << i << i++; // undefined behavior until C++17
>    a[i] = i++;       // undefined behavior until C++17
>    n = ++i + i;      // undefined behavior
>    ```

Here you can run your code with different compilers
[Evaluation order on Visual C++](https://rextester.com/RHY9363)
[Evaluation order on Zapcc and GCC](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/9Zj)

**Spoiler: Visual C++ behaves in the same way for primitive types and classes**

*On rextester you can try also Clang and GCC, but I can't add these links below the others without the editor telling me that there is some non-formatted code (which there isn't)*
[Evaluation order on Clang](https://rextester.com/EJO46104)
[Evaluation order on GCC](https://rextester.com/AIDBU50267)

Comment: i am aware i shouldn't be coding like that, but my question is why classes are behaving differently than primitives. Shouldn't they both be generating the same syntax tree as per the operators encountered in the expression.
Also float gives 22 as the result similar to int for the first case.

Comment: point 16 of the link you mentioned `Every overloaded operator obeys the sequencing rules of the built-in operator it overloads when called using operator notation.`
This clearly states that the order of evaluation for classes and primitives must be same.

Comment: @ani1998ket No, it says that it must obey the same sequencing rules, and the sequencing here is unspecified – that is, there is no rule except "do whatever you like, I don't care". The compiler isn't even required to evaluate in the same order in different executions of the program.

Comment: Those operations are unsequenced, and in precence of undefined behavior the compiler can do pretty much as it likes

Comment: @ani1998ket I've added a link where you can try a different compiler which evaluates the same expressions in a different order

Comment: @ani1998ket Is your question answered? Since you didn't accept it - it looks like an open question. The answer you've gotten looks pretty solid to me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i needed a more detailed answer on how are different syntax tree generated when classes are involved in an expression in comparison to primitives. I intentionally chose such an arithmetic expression to prove this point. Most of the answers even thought correct don't seem to explain why things behave this way and just tell them undefined. Even thought things aren't defined in the specification i strongly disagree with the fact that compiler  will be taking random guesses to evaluate any given expression.

Comment: My question is not why compilers are behaving differently but given a compiler and an expression which involves primitives and the same arithmetic expression which involves classes why is it so that in one of the cases order of evaluation is completely different from the other.    Also i have been experimenting with the syntax and i think i have found a better answer to my problem and will be updating that soon.

Comment: The compiler won't take random guesses, but you can't make assumptions on its behaviour, because it's not specified and it could (and likely will) be different on a different compiler

Comment: "_i strongly disagree with the fact that compiler will be taking random guesses to evaluate any given expression_" - Well, "guesses" may not be correct, but you are also incorrect in assuming _anything_ from a program with undefined behavior. You can have two expressions looking exactly the same in two different parts of the program and get different results from them - because undefined behavior is just that - undefined.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the explanation. Just wanted to know if that's the case is it impossible to create a class which mimics primitives such as ints and floats exactly ? Its clear according to the answers that operator overloading might behave differently for a integer expression vs a expression containing class instances.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Another thought that came to my mind was that of function calls. An expression which contains class instances although looks same as that of an expression with primitives, but actually is composed of function calls and thus leads to different parsing ?

Comment: It depends on the compiler. Even with primitive data types the same expression returns different results on different compilers.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is weird. I learned not to make any assumptions about a program's behaviour. Thanks everyone for your answers. :)